# howto get Builder to create <tag></tag> instead of <tag/>

Tags: ruby, xml, tags, builder

I,m using Builder::XmlMarkup to create xml. I want to create a tag without content because the api force me to create this.
If I use a blog

```
xml.tag do
end
```

I get what i need

```
<tag></tag>
```

but I want it shorter

```
xml.mytag
```

this gives me

```
<mytag/>
```

but i want

```
<mytag></mytag>
```

what do I have to pass as option.

regards Kai

Comment: Why do you want `<mytag></mytag>` instead of `<mytag/>`? Since the output is XML, downstream applications should not know or care about the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass empty string as a parameter. `xml.mytag('')`

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work (anymore?) Just tried this and Builder apparently is trying to be smart and creates `<tag/>` instead

Answer (score 2):

**Why** do you want `<mytag></mytag>` instead of `<mytag/>`? Since the output is XML, downstream applications should not know or care about the difference.

According to the Infoset spec ([Appendix D point 7](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#omitted)), "The difference between the two forms of an empty element: `<foo/>` and `<foo></foo>`" is not represented in the XML Information Set.

This doesn't answer your "how" question, but if you discover that you actually don't need to do what you're trying to do, it may save you from a difficult and unnecessary wild goose chase.

Comment: the problem is, Datev (the biggest german accounting-system-supplier) force me to do this. I don't think they change their api for me ;)

Comment: @toy: understood. Although it wouldn't be changing the app's behavior for *you*... it would be because they have a bug, such that they claim to consume XML but in fact they require XML formatted their way. Someone should tell them. Also it wouldn't be changing their API per se, unless their spec specifically says "short form of empty element is not allowed (or means something different)". But I understand, the reality is they're not going to fix it tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

ok empty string is nice, another one-line-way is empty block I found out.

```
xml.mytag{}
```